# Is it possible to parse this code using regex?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am working on a program that makes stratigraphic columns for geologists.  Rock units by the geologists are coded using 5 parameters: (1) a lithology code (2 characters), (2) primary code (1 character), (3) secondary code (1 character), and (4) tertiary code (1 character).  So a rock unit can be coded like:

Ssxrs - making it a rooted and cross-bedded sandstone with a sharp basal contact.

It is easy to parse out 2 characters, 1 character, 1, and 1.  But the geologist sometimes code the rock unit like:

Gr-Ss --- where the unit grades upward from a conglomerate to a sandstone, or

Gr/Ss --- where the conglomerate and sandstone are interbedded.

They can do this multiple times like:

Gr-Ss/Ls --- where a conglomerate grades upward to an interbedded sandstone and limestone.  Not only do they do this for the lithology codes but also for the primary, secondary, and tertiary codes.

I would like to parse out the 5 code streams and actions (ie. "/" and "-") into a lithology list/array, primary list/array, secondary list/array, and tertiary list/array.

Is this a regex solvable problem?

Comment: `Parsing <> Regex` IMO so to answer your question - No

Comment: One regex or multiple regexes? Are you interested in answers that don't use a regex(es)?

Comment: Seems likely, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around your problem.  Maybe if you provide some example inputs/outputs?

Comment: Please post some sample input data.  It does seem like a regex solvable problem to me.

Comment: Lithology
    Lg/Lphf/bt
    Lgmft
    Lgmfi
    Lghft
    Lgm/xft
    Lpxfi
    Lpmft
    Fthfi
    Lp/Lgmfi
    La/Fthfg
    Fthfi
    Simfi
    Fthf/bs
    Lgxb/fs
    Simfi
    Lghfs
    Fthbs
    Lgx/mft
    Simfi
    Ss-Fthbi
Here's some typical lithologic data.  It looks like Pierre-Louis understood me, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex :

```
((?:[A-Za-z]{2}[-\/])*[A-Za-z]{2})((?:[A-Za-z][-\/])*[A-Za-z])((?:[A-Za-z][-\/])*[A-Za-z])((?:[A-Za-z][-\/])*[A-Za-z])
```

will allow you to find the 4 differents code in 4 differents groups : http://rubular.com/r/Y7rlT09soH

Some explanations :
first capturing group :

`((?:[A-Za-z]{2}[-\/])*[A-Za-z]{2})`

will capture, 0 or more time, 2 letters followed by a "-" or a "/", followed by 2 letters.
(The "?:" is for no capturing group)

The 3 next capturing group are identical :

```
((?:[A-Za-z][-\/])*[A-Za-z])
```

They will do the same as the first one but with only one letter.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  This greatly simplified the code I had developed.  I keep the codes in Dictionaries that makes it easy to look whether the code is valid and the colors, symbology, etc. that need to be draw in the graphic.